# How do I select all the files (exclude all the directories) in a folder?

Tags: bash

Say I have a folder with many files and directories (NOT actual filenames, this is like a trash can directory, so the filenames are completely random, and some files are without extension):

```
dir1/
dir2/
...
dirN/
file1
file2
...
fileM
```

Now I need to move all the *files* in this directory into the `dir1/`. That is, move `file1`, `file2` ... `fileM` into `dir1/`. What's the easiest way to do that?

If they are all files with extension then the problem is simple, just `mv *.* dir1/`. But I don't know what to do if there are files without extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} dir1/ \;`

Comment: Could do with `+` instead of `\;` if your `find` supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Although `find` is a good solution, here is another solution using bash only :

```
for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && mv "$file" dir1; done
```

Comment: Compared to the `find` solution, this one will not handle the hidden files, unless the shell option `dotglob` is set. Moreover, if a filename starts with a hyphen, this will confuse `mv`; to address this latter issue, either use `for file in ./*; do` or `mv -- "$files" dir1`. Another remark: this solution uses bash globbing that can be very slow if there are lots of files, since globbing performs a sort; the `find` solution doesn't sort files, so will be much faster, especially if used in the form: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} dir1/ +`.

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not have a direct way to select only regular files. You have to use `find` for that.

Maybe `zsh` is also an option for you. With `zsh` you could simply write

```
mv *(.) dir1/
```

Answer (score -2):

One way:

```
mv $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type f) dir1
```

Another:

```
for file in *; do
if [ -f "$file" ]
then mv "$file" dir1
fi
done
```

Comment: You meant `find * -maxdepth 0 -type f` right? From a quick experiment I think `-maxdepth` should be `0` to exclude files in `dir1/`.

Comment: @trVoldemort More likely accidental `*`

Comment: Are you on crack or what? `mv $(find * -maxdepth 1 -type f) dir1` is the worst command I've ever seen! You wildcard will expand to all the files and dirs in current directory, and this will confuse find. Moreover if there are any spaces or funny symbols in the found file, this will very badly break.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: That's exactly the problem I come back to report. It stucks with files containing spaces.

Comment: @trVoldemort Use user3553031's answer!

Comment: Moreover, you forgot the `fi` in your second command. And you could use `for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && mv "$file" dir1; done` instead (although `find` is still a better solution).